# Custom textures in new "Fields" Geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does anyone know how to use custom image textures in the new Fields refactor of geometry nodes? There used to be a node called attribute sample texture, I cannot find the equivalent now. Thanks in advance!
Blender 3.0

Comment: I think there will be an 'Image Texture' node, it just hasn't been added yet.

Comment: Not every node has been converted to the new system yet

Comment: thank you, i was kinda hoping that was the case but couldn't find anything on the sub